# How can I make 'diff -X' ignore specific paths and not file names?

Tags: linux, diff

Doing:
`diff -r -X <ignore-list> <src-dir> <dest-dir>`

doesn't seem to make `diff` ignore entries in `<ignore-list>` if they are of the form `<dir>/<file>`.

Entries of the form `<file`> do however get considered. This is a problem since I
might have multiple files named `<file>` in different sub-directories,
some of which I don't want ignored.

There doesn't seem to be much information regarding pattern syntax in
the manpage for `diff` either. From what I can tell, it's just the base-name of a file that is considered by diff (see http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-889788-start-0.html if you're interested).

Comment: man, `diff` 's `--exclude` option is so shitty...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Listing directories should work; e.g., here's what I've used in a script (assuming gnu diff),

```
diff -r \
   --exclude="*~" \
   --exclude=".svn" \
   --exclude=".git" \
   --exclude="*.zip*" \
   --exclude="*.gz" \
   --exclude="*.tar" \
   ...etc
```

...which ignores contents of `.svn` and `.git` dirs, but also individual files named `*.zip`/`*.gz`/etc.

**Edit:** In order to filter paths of the form `dir_a/file1` but still `diff` files with the same basename, such as `dir_b/file1` or `dir_a/b/file1`, then a list of files to `diff` would have to be generated (for example, using `find`), and the file to compare derived from these paths; e.g., given

```
$ find ONE TWO -type f -print 
ONE/a/1.txt
ONE/a/2.txt
ONE/a/b/2.txt
TWO/a/1.txt
TWO/a/2.txt
TWO/a/b/2.txt
```

you generate the list of files to compare, excluding for example `*/a/2.txt` but still comparing other files named `2.txt`.  Just "find" all files except `ONE/a/2.txt` (a regexp can also be used here, such as `.*/a/2.txt`)

```
$ find ONE -type f \( ! -regex 'ONE/a/2.txt' \) \
    -exec bash -c 'diff -q "${1}" "${2/ONE/TWO}"' - {} {} \;
```

which in effect ignores `ONE/a/2.txt` (and `TWO/a/2.txt`), but still compares the other files named `2.txt`:

```
diff -q ONE/a/1.txt TWO/a/1.txt
diff -q ONE/a/b/2.txt TWO/a/b/2.txt
```

**Edit:** Or, more fun with `find` (additional fun left as an exercise for the reader), select the files or directories to *exclude* and then `diff` everything else:

```
$ find ONE \( -regex 'ONE/a/2.txt' -o -name b  -prune \)  \
    -o -type f -exec bash -c 'echo diff -q "${1}" "${2/ONE/TWO}"' - {} {} \
```

The above example excludes the specific file "{top}/a/2.txt", any directory named "b", and everything else is diff'd.  (Instead of simple "`-name b`" you could also use "`-regex '.*/b'`" - note, no trailing "/".)

Comment: Thanks but I think you're missing the point. The only support there seems to be is when you use a 'base-name'. That could be the name of a directory or a file. In either case, diff ignores what you've asked for. The problem arises when you use paths. For example, I can't get diff to ignore /an/absolute/path/to/a/file or ./a/relative/path/to/a/file.

Comment: diff --exclude="/this/specific/file/that/im/explicitly/pleading/you/to/ignore". It won't work.

Comment: correct, `exclude` patterns are matched against the files' basename (as per http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Comparing-Directories.html#Comparing-Directories); paths will not work (as in `foo/bar.txt`). To do that, you will likely have to run `find` to generate the list of filenames, and derive the path to the file to compare.

Comment: updated answer to include example excluding file paths from the `diff`, instead of just using `basename`

Comment: Okay, I see what you're proposing but there appears to be a problem. I need to consider directories as well, not just files (i.e -type f). Now, while you can still prune out certain files using regexp with `find`, if the input to `diff` contains a directory, it will go through and compare files within that directory and some of these files might need to be ignored....so you're back to square 1.

Comment: @Ash No, not at all.  Note I didn't use `diff -r`, which would defeat the purpose of using `find`.  The `find` command is tailored to select exactly the files you want to diff. Luckily it is very, very flexible. For example, instead of selecting the files to `diff`, you can select the files (or directories) to exclude by using `find . \(stuff to exclude... -prune \) -o ...stuff to diff`, for example: `find ONE \( -regex 'ONE/a/2.txt' -o -name b  -prune \) -o -type f -exec bash -c 'echo diff -q "${1}" "${2/ONE/TWO}"' - {} {} \;`

Comment: In your example, you've passed the `-type f` argument to `find`. If you leave this out, the `find` result might contain directories. Let's say, the result contained the directory `foo`. `diff -q ONE/foo TWO/foo` will cause `diff` to compare files within those directories, even the ones you may have wanted to ignore using `find`. Also, I'm not sure how flexible `find` actually is. Reading through the manpage, there doesn't appear to be an option to exclude symlinks. The `-type l` option selects symlinks only but there's no option to ignore them.

Comment: I'm possibly not making myself clear, so I'll use the files in your example. I need `find` to list directories as well. To do this, I need to leave out `-type f`. If I do this, the `find` result will contain the directory `a`. Now `diff -q ONE/a TWO/a` will cause `diff` to compare the files `ONE/a/2.txt` and `TWO/a/2.txt`. See the problem?

Comment: I've got around the problem by simply checking each entry in the `find` result to see whether it's a directory or file. I only `diff` if it's a file. I need to list sub-directories as well, since I'm comparing two directories and I need to know all the differences. Accepted your answer as it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to hear you've got something working, but... for posterity: _"you've passed the type -f to find. If you leave this out, the result might contain directories"_ => correct: so, don't leave it out. I added it for a reason. No need to recursive diff if you're already using recursive `find`. _"I need find to list directories"_ => no, you don't; you need the files in directories to be listed, and `find` does that. _"No option to exclude symlinks"_ => using `-type f` does exclude symlinks; alternatively, use `-type l -prune -o` will exclude symlinks (use in my example w/ patterns to exclude)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned the background to my problem. I'm writing a backup system and therefore need to list directories. That is, when comparing SOURCE and DESTINATION, I might need to know if directories exist in SOURCE but not in DESTINATION (and vice versa). Anyway, things are working now. I'm using `find` followed by `comm` and finally `diff`ing appropriate files. Also, I'm using `-type f and -type d` with `find`. Symlinks are therefore ignored.

Comment: true, could have saved a lot of time. just install rsync :-) (seriously, just install rsync)

Comment: I'm doing delta backups (date based, with history....similar to `rdiff-backup`, except my system doesn't crash almost everyday with obscure messages). `rsync` doesn't do that. I do use `rsync` for the actual copying though.

Comment: If you don't want to type --exclude every time use -x ".svn"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem so I created a patch to `diff`. The patch has yet to be accepted, but you can build your own version of `diff` with the patch or [install on Arch Linux with an AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/diffutils-patched-exclude-directory-git).

[Here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-diffutils/2016-05/msg00008.html) is the `diff` patch.

Comment: Hi, I need to use this feature on Ubuntu (Debian based). Could you please make a version for apt/deb? Unless there is a way to install the "AUR" on Ubuntu? I don't know too much about Arch and it's package manager, all I've used besides apt is Fedora yum.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been keeping up with this patch and nobody merge the patch into `diff` AFAIK. You could try building `diff` from source to get the feature you want.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude directory `directory/sub-directory`, I use

```
diff -r <src-dir> <dest-dir> | grep -v directory/sub-directory
```

However, although it should work for a single exclude, it should not be possible for a long ignore list as you have.

Answer (score -3):

```
$ diff -rq foo.orig foo | grep -vP 'ignore1/|exclude2/' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f2- | xargs -I{} diff -u foo.orig/{} foo/{}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.